# PCA Reduction resulted in an elliptical form

Tags: python, scikit-learn, clustering, pca

I have a dataset with 19 features (columns). I normalized them using `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` then I used PCA to reduce them to 2 components for plotting purposes following the steps in this link:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html

What I saw is that my data points form a perfect ellipse shape as in the following picture:
[image: K-means clustering with PCA reduction]

I want to know if this has any special meaning for my data.

Comment: You probably broke your data.